# Is there any ellipsis in "The dog is somewhere about, hunting rats"?

Tags: ellipses

I saw this sentence in a story book.

> The dog is somewhere about, hunting rats

Does it omit [a place] after "somewhere about"? If so, what is this type of ellipsis?

> The dog is somewhere about [a place], hunting rats

Comment: The subject of _hunting rats_ is deleted, presumably by coreference with the subject of _be somewhere about_. _Be somewhere about_ can be most simply treated as a locative predicate adjective, though if you prefer you can go to the trouble of making it short for _be somewhere about the premises_ or something.

Comment: What you have is a compound verb, consisting of "is somewhere about" and "is hunting rats".  "And" and the second "is" has been elided.  "Somewhere about" is an idiom meaning "nearby".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ellipsis is an omission of words that are readily understood from the context.  For example:

> I was born in 1960; she, three years later.

Supplying the missing words:

> I was born in 1960, [and] she [was born] three years later.

The semicolon in the first sentence indicates the missing conjunction, and the comma indicates the missing parallel verb.

Your sentence has no such omissions.  Its structure is

> **S** - **cV** - **AdvC** - **nA**

**S** (Subject) = "The dog"
**cV** (copulative Verb) = "is"
**AdvC** (Adverbial complement) = "somewhere about"
**nA** (nominative Absolute) = "hunting rats"

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking if the first sentence is grammatically correct, it is. "Somewhere about" is idiomatic usage that implies "somewhere about *here*" (in relation to the speaker). The "here" doesn't have to be explicitly included. The sentence means that the dog is somewhere in the vicinity of the speaker and is engaged in hunting rats.